# postgresql-setup not reading PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

`postgresql-setup --help` outputs:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/postgresql-setup MODE_OPTION [--unit=UNIT_NAME] [OPTION...]

...

Available operation mode:
  --initdb      Initialize new PostgreSQL database cluster.  This is usually the
                first action you perform after PostgreSQL server installation.
...
Environment:
  PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS     Options carried by this variable are passed to
                             subsequent call of `initdb` binary (see man
                             initdb(1)).  This variable is used also during
                             'upgrade' mode because the new cluster is actually
                             re-initialized from the old one.
```

However when I run something like:

```
> export PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS="--auth=scram-sha-256 --username=admin_user --pwprompt /var/lib/pgsql/data";
> sudo postgresql-setup --initdb
```

It doesn't seem to apply the options in `PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS`. The auth in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` still reads:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

(None are scram-sha-256)

Also, I wasn't prompted for a password and super user still seems to be `postgres`.

I'm using:

- postgresql 12.11
- Os: Rocky Linux release 8.6 (Green Obsidian)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Never heard of `postgresql-setup`, where did you get it from? Add answer as update to question.

Comment: It comes with the default installation of postgres 12 when I installed: [example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-and-setup-postgresql-on-rhel-8/)

Comment: 1) To be clear this is RH family default not a Postgres default. There is no such program in the Postgres core software. 2) Where there any errors when you ran `sudo postgresql-setup --initdb`? 3) Why not use `initdb` directly?

Comment: 1) Oh that's good to know. I thought that was part of postgres. 2) No there weren't any errors. 3) Yes, this turned out to be the solution. Was able to set up postgres how I wanted like that. Happy, to accept that as the answer if you want to post one.

Comment: I believe sudo doesn't pass the invoker's environment into the new user's environment by default.

Comment: @jjanes I think that might be the issue. Haven't had to chance to test it but I have a feeling that would fix it.